# How to detect incoming calls in Android even when the app is terminated

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver which detects incoming calls and starts an activity. But it doesnt work sometimes in real devices. How can I make it work all the time?

My receiver :

```
        <receiver android:name="InterceptCall"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

onReceive method

```
    @Override
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        try {
            val state: String? = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            val incomingNumber: String? =
                intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Log.d("INFO", incomingNumber.toString())
                Toast.makeText(context, "Gelen Arama $incomingNumber", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if(incomingNumber != null){
                    simpleFloatingWindow = SimpleFloatingWindow(context!!)
                    simpleFloatingWindow.show()
                }
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                //Toast.makeText(context,"Call Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                //Toast.makeText(context,"Call Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start an activity from the background from Android 10+ devices. Except for the cases:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions

Comment: But there is a bunch of apps that can do it. For example I inspired this app from UpCall which detects incoming calls and shows a dialog. It works well in my phone. (Android 11)

Comment: Please check that link and read the last point. The app you mentioned might have implemented draw over app permission aka SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

Comment: I have this permission in my manifest and my activity works well. But sometimes, for example when the user does not open the app for 3-4 days it doesnt work well. Should I use services or something else?

Comment: @AhmetBugraOzcan How did you proceed with that? Did you have success?